# Working with Javascript and images in AIR's HTML component

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, webkit, air

I'm having the following problems using Javascript and img tags in the standard HTML component in AIR:

1- Javascript in the xml literal causes problems (even though it shows using them here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_07.html#1032824

2- Using `html.loadString(...<img src="/tmp/me.jpg" />...)` does not show the image.

3- After wrapping the Javascript in CDATA tags it is still not accessible and returns an 'invalid function' error when trying to reach it.

The second 2 issues seem to go away if I save the html to a file and load it with `html.load(file)` instead of trying to read it as a string. Any suggestions to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving the file to a temporary file and using `html.load(tempfile)`.